# How to grab ID of multiple input field and sum them in a span as total

Tags: javascript

I have the following

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="total1" id="total1">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="total1" id="total2">
```

I already get these two values using javascript.

but I want to display the result in a span like below or a P tag

```
<span id="sum">0</span>
```

I tried the following...but i want it to be auto...meaning once the input field if there, total should also appear

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">

function output(){
    var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2);
}

function updateTextInput(val) {
          document.getElementById('value2').value=val; 
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Please show us your jquery, then we can better guide you on what is wrong with your current code.

Comment: Emmanuel from what i can see the problem is `document.getElementById('result')` is looking for an element with the id `result` but you have `<span id="sum">0</span>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the result you can simply use

Javascript : `document.getElementById("sum").innerText = SumOfTwoValues`

Jquery : `$("#sum").text(SumOfTwoValues);`

Please make sure you add required validations for the Summation value before assigning it.

Answer (score 0):

With vanilla javascript

```js
function a()
{
var a1=document.querySelectorAll('input')
let sum=0;
for(let i=0;i<a1.length;i++)
sum+=Number(a1[i].value)
document.querySelector('#e').innerHTML=sum
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="total1" id="total1" onchange="a()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="total1" id="total2" onchange="a()">
<p id="e"></p>
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to get the ID's of the input but more like the total value of the inputs

Comment: all the options work...but i have to manually call the function like this <input type="submit" onclick="add();">....but i want to be able to get the answer on change function, or once i input something

Comment: Thanks for ur help...pls how can i make <p id="e"></p> returns in money format

Answer (score 0):

Well first of you need some way to call the function `output`.

Now there are a few problems regarding the Ids of the elements, you have `id="total1"` but you are trying to call `getElementById('value1')`.

same goes for `total2` and  `sum`.

Last I would add `|| 0` after your `.value` so incase 1 of the input's haven't been filled, then it set to 0, so we can use it as a number.

```js
function output() {
  var value1 = document.getElementById('total1').value || 0;
  var value2 = document.getElementById('total2').value || 0;
  document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" oninput="output()" name="total1" id="total1">
<input type="text" class="form-control" oninput="output()" name="total1" id="total2">

<span id="sum">0</span>
```

Comment: let me try this now and get back..thank u in advance

Comment: how do i call the function output...i think its not calling that function

Comment: @EmmanuelIyen-Mediatrees I've added  oninput="output()" to my inputs

Comment: oninput="output()" doesnt work on realtime...for example if u enter 2 for a second it gives u the total, still on that input field if u add 3 making it 23, new result wount appear...it will show old result only

Answer (score 0):

Calculation in one line of Javascript.

```js
function calc() {
  document.querySelector('#sum').innerHTML = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].reduce((acc, input) => acc + Number(input.value), 0);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="total1" id="total1" onchange="calc()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="total1" id="total2" onchange="calc()">
<p id="sum"></p>
```